# $\mathrm{ILP}$-formulation for Minimum Maximal Matching (MMM) Problem

Tags: linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, matching-theory

Despite some online searching I couldn't find examples of dedicated Integer Linear Programs ($\mathrm{ILP}$s) for determining smallest matchings, that are not contained in a larger one.
It seems that the following could be an example of such an $\mathrm{ILP}$:

$\quad\quad\min\quad \sum\limits_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace\subset \lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace}x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}$,

s.t.

$x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$

$x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}+\sum\limits_{h\ne i}x_{\lbrace h,j\rbrace}+\sum\limits_{k\ne j}x_{\lbrace i,k\rbrace}\ \in\ \lbrace 1,2\rbrace,\quad\forall \lbrace h,i,j,k\rbrace\subseteq\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$

> **Questions:**
>
> - has the above $\mathrm{ILP}$ formulation of the MMM problem already appeared in the literature?
> - what is know resp. can be said, about the integrality gap of the relaxed $\mathrm{LP}$-formulation, i.e. when
>   $\quad\quad\min\quad \sum\limits_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace\subset \lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace}x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}$,
>
> $\quad$ s.t.
>
> $\quad x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}\in\left[ 0,1\right]$
>
> $\quad x_{\lbrace i,j\rbrace}+\sum\limits_{h\ne i}x_{\lbrace h,j\rbrace}+\sum\limits_{k\ne j}x_{\lbrace i,k\rbrace}\ \in\ \left[1,2\right],\quad\forall \lbrace h,i,j,k\rbrace\subseteq\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the *independent domination number* of the line graph.  I have used a similar ILP formulation to find the independent domination number of various graphs:

- https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22independent+domination+number%22
- https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22independent+domination+number%22

As shown in some of those posts, the ceiling of the optimal LP objective value provides a lower bound but is not always equal to the optimal ILP objective value.  I don't know whether any of those instances arise as line graphs.

Comment: while I see the equivalence of the MMM problem to the *independent domination number* of the line graph, I couldn't find the corresponding formulation as (or even mention of) an LP when following the links in your answer; did I overlook something?

Comment: One of the links leads to my ILP formulation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374862/the-minimum-n-times-n-square-covering-problem-for-1-times-4-shaped-tetromi/3376219#3376219, and this one mentions the LP bound: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109240/minimize-1%c3%973-tiles-on-a-5%c3%975-table-to-block-any-more-1%c3%973-tiles/109245#109245